# UITapRecognizer not working with ImageView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, uitapgesturerecognizer

I am currently trying to make a signout button for an app.

I have the `UIImageView` "User Interaction Enabled" box checked.

in my `.h` file I have this:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *signOutButtonIV;
```

in my .m file I have this:

```
- (void) viewDidLoad{

[super viewDidLoad];

    UITapGestureRecognizer* tapGestureRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tapResponder:)];

    tapGestureRecognizer.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
    tapGestureRecognizer.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1;
    [self.signOutButtonIV addGestureRecognizer:tapGestureRecognizer];

}

-(void) tapResponder:(UITapGestureRecognizer *) sender{
    NSLog(@"single tap detected");
}
```

If I instead use `[self addGestureRecognizer:tapGestureRecognizer]` the taps will be detected. Is there a step I am missing?

Comment: Can you log `userInteractionEnabled` before adding gesture recognizer?

Comment: is there any particular reason for using `UIImageView` instead of `UIButton` ?

Comment: @ArtemNovichkov I checked and it was not enabled! I have the box checked in the story board under triats for "User Interaction Enabled". But that did not seem to work. Thank you

Comment: @RatulSharker would it be ok to put an invisble button over an image view? I tried but I kept encountering an error "Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<UIViewController 0x6e36ae0> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key XXX.'

Comment: Actually i intend to use [setImage](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uibutton/1623997-setimage?language=objc) . The above error is saying you have added an IBOutlet / IBAction, but this not declared in the code implementation.

Comment: Why use an imageView? I think you can use a button with an image background? then you can change the image based on the control

Answer (score 0):

Add following lines

```
[self.signOutButtonIV setUserInteractionEnabled:YES]; 
[PARENT_VIEW bringSubviewToFront:self.signOutButtonIV];
```

before `[self.signOutButtonIV addGestureRecognizer:tapGestureRecognizer];`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Artem Novichkov pointed out to Log the userEnabledInteraction.

The log came back false. Even though i had checked the box in the storyboard file it was not enabled.

```
[signOutButtonIV setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
```

was what was needed to fix my problem.

Thanks Artem!

Answer (score 0):

Can also use storyboard to achieve the results:-

[image]

Comment: Yes, I had that exact box checked (as explained in my question)